# Storing big matrices in C++ (Armadillo)

Tags: c++, matrix, armadillo

I'm using the [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) library in C++ for storing / calculating large matrices. It is my understanding that one should store large arrays / matrices dynamically (on the heap).

Suppose I declare a matrix

```
mat X;
```

and set the size to be (say) 500 rows, 500 columns with random entries:

```
X.randn(500,500);
```

Does Armadillo store `X` dynamically (i.e. on the heap) despite not using `new` or `delete`.? The reason I ask, is because it seems Armadillo allows me to declare a variable as:

```
mat::fixed<n_rows, n_cols>
```

which, I [quote](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html): "is generally faster than dynamic memory allocation, but the size of the matrix can't be changed afterwards (directly or indirectly)".

Regardless of the above -- should I use this:

```
mat A;
A.set_size(n-1,n-1);
```

or this:

```
mat *A = new mat;
(*A).set_size(n-1,n-1);
```

where n is between 1000 or 100000 and not known in advance.

Comment: `100000*100000*4` is about 40 GB which might require virtual memory and introduce a whole boatload of problems.

Comment: In general I recommend against using pointers, as they're easy to get wrong: they often lead to memory leaks or memory corruption. Pointers are generally only useful inside well-tested libraries, not in user code. When passing objects to functions, it's better to use references. To store a set of objects, use container classes [instead](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html) of C arrays containing pointers.

Comment: @Mikhail Is there a way to memory map the array? I'd like to get more speed, so I'm considering Armadillo, but Numpy I use right now can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does Armadillo store X dynamically (i.e. on the heap) despite not
>   using `new` or `delete`.?

Yes. There will be some form of `new` or `delete` in the library code. You just don't notice it from the outside.

> The reason I ask, is because it seems Armadillo
>   allows me to declare a variable as (`mat::fixed` ...)

You'd have to look into the source code to see what's going on exactly here. My guess is that it has some kind of internal logic that decides how to deal with things based on size. You would normally use `mat::fixed` for small matrices, though.

Following that, you should use

```
mat A(n-1,n-1);
```

if you know the size at that point already. In some cases,

```
mat A;
A.set_size(n-1,n-1);
```

might also be okay.

I can't think of a good reason to use your second option with the `mat *` pointer. First of all, libraries like armadillo handle their memory allocations internally, and developers take great care to get it right. Also, even if the memory code in the library was broken, your idea `new mat` wouldn't fix it: You would allocate memory for a `mat` object, but that object is certainly rather small. The big part is probably hidden behind something like a member variable `T* data` in the class `mat`, and you cannot influence how this is allocated from the outside.

I initially missed your comment on the size of `n`. As Mikhail says, dealing with 100000x100000 matrices will require much more care than simply thinking about the way you instantiate them.

Comment: Thank you for your well written explanation. About the large n: am I right in thinking, though, that if I have access to a computer which has 512GB of RAM (not hard drive space) -- it would run fine?

Comment: @user2432701 I would image it would run fine then (under the assumption that there's no memory limit for individual processes!). But you also have to consider the run time! If you try more complicated stuff, it may well be that it doesn't finish in our lifetime.

Comment: Thanks again for your advice. When you say "I can't think of a good reason to use your second option with the mat * pointer" -- well, would an acceptable time be when I need to store a large array of large matrices? If not, why?

Comment: @fushsialatitude In general, I wouldn't recommend it. The bookkeeping data for a `mat` seems to be about 160 bytes (`sizeof(mat)`). Compared to the data block for a large matrix (500x500x8 bytes = 2MB), that's minimal. So I personally would recommend a `std::vector<mat>` for a large array of large matrices.

Comment: You can also use Armadillo's [field class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#field) to store multiple matrices, eg. `field<mat>`. The advantage over `std::vector<mat>` is that `field<mat>` can refer to stored objects in a 2D layout, ie. you can have a matrix of matrices. It's also possible to use [.save()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_field) to store a `field<mat>` object as a file.